# PHP format date returning duplicates

Tags: php, sql, date-format

Im trying to get the DISTINCT month and year from the DB. Format the dates and put them into a drop down list. But im getting all the records as being Jan 14

Heres my code:

```
            <select name="month">
                <?php
                    $sSDate = "SELECT DISTINCT year(eventStartDate), month(eventStartDate) FROM te_events GROUP BY eventStartDate ORDER BY eventStartDate ASC";
                    $qrSDate = mysql_query($sSDate) or die (mysql_error());
                    while($rowSDate = mysql_fetch_assoc($qrSDate))
                    {
                        $s_event_start_month = $rowSDate ['month(eventStartDate)'];
                        $s_event_start_year = $rowSDate ['year(eventStartDate)'];

                        $date = date("M", strtotime($s_event_start_month)). date("y", strtotime($s_event_start_year));

                        echo '
                        <option value="'.$date.'">
                            '.$date.'
                        </option>
                        ';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if i fully understand the problem but please try this:

```
$date = date("M y", strtotime($s_event_start_month.' '.$s_event_start_year));
```

or

```
$date = date("M y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $s_event_start_month, 1, $s_event_start_year));
```

[about mktime](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Comment: Yeah just figured it like literally 5 seconds ago. You right, it was the mktime that was the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year(eventStartDate)
, month(eventStartDate) 
FROM te_events 
GROUP BY eventStartDate 
ORDER BY eventStartDate ASC
```

Since distinct years and months are separate fields, you are getting more combinations than you want.  If you want distinct year-months, which makes more sense, you want something like this:

```
select distinct to_char(eventStartDate, 'yyyy-mm') ym
from te_events
where whatever, maybe
order by ym
```

Your question does not specify the database engine, so for the sake of this answer, I picked oracle.  Different databases have different ways of achieving the same result.

Comment: Thanks. But i still need the date the way it is in the DB. Basically this is one element of my Advanced search form, so to search the DB, i still need the date unformatted. You understand ?

Comment: I don't have to understand, it's your application.  But I do notice a disconnect between your comment to my answer and the prose and code in your question.